# Why is my register-constant comparison not working in NASM Assembly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, nasm

Learning NASM Assembly in 32-bit Ubuntu.

This is giving me headaches: suppose that I have an array (I call it vector in the program) in `.data`:

```
vector db  1,2,3,4
size   equ $-vector
```

And I also have a number `0`:

```
index  db 0
```

I want to store `size` in `EBX`, then store `index` in `ECX`, and finally check if `ECX < EBX`. In this example, it would be `0 < 4`. My program simply doesn't do it:

```
SECTION .data
    vector  db  1,2,3,4
    size    equ $-vector

    index   db  0

    ; Vocabulary
    msg1    db  "ECX < EBX",10
    msg1len equ $-msg1
    msg2    db  "ECX >= EBX",10
    msg2len equ $-msg2

SECTION .text
global main
main:
; -----------------------------------------------
; MAIN
; -----------------------------------------------
    mov EBX,size     ; EBX = 4
    mov ECX,[index]  ; ECX = 0
    call    check    ; Check ECX < EBX (0 < 4)

; -----------------------------------------------
; EXIT
; -----------------------------------------------
mov EAX,1
int 0x80

; -----------------------------------------------
; Check
; Checks whether ECX < EBX
; -----------------------------------------------
check:
cmp ECX,EBX
jge greater_or_equal

mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov ECX,msg1
mov EDX,msg1len
int 0x80
jmp end_check

greater_or_equal:

mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov ECX,msg2
mov EDX,msg2len
int 0x80

end_check:

ret
```

It outputs:

> ECX >= EBX

But that's just not right. `ECX` should be 0 and `EBX` should be 4.

I don't see the problem - but I do have an observation:

```
mov EBX,size
```

This line bugs me - I wanted to do this:

```
mov EBX,[size]
```

But I would get a segmentation fault. I didn't know that would happen, but I'm guessing that it is because `size` isn't an address - it's just a number, so I can't use the brackets on it. I might be wrong (in which case this could be the cause of the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
index   db  0
msg1    db  "ECX < EBX",10

mov  ecx, [index]
```

`index` is defined as `db`, so the instruction will move to `ecx` this 0 and 3 more bytes from `msg1`

Use:

```
index dd 0
```

Comment: Ahhhh, the moment I realize all my NASM programs have this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Standard beginner error. 
That is still happening to me  actually, if i do not pay attention as i should because a problem to solve sounds "too easy"  :-)

Comment: Actually, it'd be better to `mov cl, [index]`.