# What happens when I copy a constant defined with EQU into EAX in NASM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

After having headaches with [Why is my register-constant comparison not working in NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18819863/555690), turns out that I've been copying 1-byte variables (`db`) to `EAX`, meaning that the three bytes after the variable would be copied as well. Now that I know this, I'm looking at my code for similar scenarios, and found this:

In `.data` I have an array and its size defined in a constant:

```
array  db   1,2,3,4
size   equ  $-array
```

Later, in `.text` I have this:

```
mov EAX,size
```

This made me wonder: what exactly is happening there? What size is `size`? Is it a byte? A word? Is EAX receiving extra bytes it shouldn't be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [an immediate](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-immediate.html), and the assembler should choose the most appropriate size for it (if there's more than one possible encoding). If the smallest possible size exceeds the size of the target register you should get an error, or at least a warning.

In your example, the line `mov EAX,size` would assemble as if you had typed `mov EAX,4`.

Answer (score 2):

It is immediate value calculated from actual position minus start of `array`. 
Important difference between `equ` and `%define` is that compiler replaces `$` symbol directly where `equ` is used, while `%define` is just textual representation useful when preprocessing code, so the `$` is different for every occurence. Corresponding code using `%define` is

```
array: db 1, 2, 3, 4
array_end: 
%define array_end - array
```

Although `equ` might seem perfect for array data manipulations, `%define` is useful for stringss.

What exactly happens when compiler gets to your instruction?
It simply replaces the name of constant with its already calculated value. Compiler then encodes the instruction as follows:

```
mov r32, imm -> 0xB8 + 0x00 (for EAX)
size         -> 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Another registers have different values which can be found in Intel Manuals. The addition to `0xB8` is Intel´s trick to save 1 byte, which would be used for storing `REG` code in `ModR/M` byte.

Instructions generally don't usually use such trick, but some frequent instructions save one byte by using special opcode for accumulator register.